# Is an integrable map from a measure space to a Banach space always measurable?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

> Is every integrable mapping  defined in a general measure space to a Banach space  measurable?

The answer is yes if it is function (real valued). The answer is yes if it is a mapping into a Banach space but defined on euclidean space.

The monograph by J. Mikisuinski says that you must add this fact as an axiom for general Bochner integral. Serge Lang in his book "real analysis" defines Lebesgue integral for mappings into a Banach space and specifically insists on measurability but definition makes sense if a mapping f is not measurable but | f| is |f| is a real valued function .
 So why should we force measurability?

As far as I know, nobody has given a specific mapping say on a locally compact space to a Banach space which is integrable and of course |f| measurable but f not measurable.Can somebody furnish an actual example?
Will it involve transfinite induction (axiom of choice in some form)?
Will it involve a cardinal greater than the cardinal number of real line? a transfinite induction in some sense of higher order? These questions are not at all addressed.

Comment: If possible, could you please edit your post to fix the spelling and capitalization? 

Comment: Perhaps you will need to provide a definition of "integrable" as well.

Comment: also: "measurable" wrto which sigma-algebra on the Banach space?

Comment: a general question .measurable with respect to arbitrary measure space. domain is arbitrary . i mean range is Banach space.
 integrable as defined for Lebesgue/Bochner.


Comment:  i have very carefully given added info from Lang and Mikisuinski. this issue is not at all addressed.
following treatment of Lang ( or as done in miksuinski's monograph directly) we can define integral fora map . the map need not be measurable of course |f| shall continue to be measurable
 in addition see Lang's treatment and carefully a measurable map taking values in finite dime euclidean space is almost everywhere limit of simple maps. not true in general.
 

Comment: also see that Lang distinguishes carefully in simple maps and step maps. though definitions are verbatim similar with difference only in fine print which can make integral define for a non measurable map.
Mikisunski directly says that an integrable map need not be measurable ( if u follow Mikisuinski approach to Bochner integral).
You need to add it as axiom. also interestingly then are u getting a space strictly larger than L1 if u allow such maps ( only in case of Banach valued i.e infinite dimensional maps).
 i hope this question will start a discussion ?

Comment: I have edited the question (mostly just punctuation) so that it is hopefully a bit easier to read.

Comment: You seem to think that every reader out here will rush to the library, borrow the monographs of Lang and Mikisuinski (Mikusinski?) and go through a painstaking effort to figure out the substance of your question. Dream on! You have better odds of getting responses if you make some effort to explain the issues.

Comment: Michael, I think that's a bit harsh (although I admit I am not rushing to sit down and think about this particular question). This seems like the sort of question that more, erm, classically trained folk than me might happen to know off-hand

Comment: Wikipedia has definitions of the Bochner integral (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral), Bochner space (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_space) and Bochner measurability (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_measurable_function). I assume these are the intended definitions.

Comment: Maybe the question is asking whether Bochner measurable functions are measurable in the usual sense with respect to the Borel sigma-algebra. But I'm not sure.

Comment: 1)i think i am very clear. definition of integral is standard ( bochner integral is simply lebesgue integral but mappings have values in a Banach space,
2) i have also made it clear  that as per lang's treatment integrable map f is one for which there is sequence of step maps converging almost everywhere , and which is cauchy in L1 norm. the  adjective measurable is attached to f by lang,



Comment: 3) when u go through mikisunisis treatment ( Daniell Archimedies ) if you have a series of mappings ( from a Dasniell lattice) which is converging at all the points to a map f(x) ,where the integral of the modulus of step mappings is convergent then f is integrable. he clearly specifies in the mono graph that we have to add an axiom that an integrable i map is measurable
4) in two cases 1)when domain isa arbitrary measure space range if real line(or finite dim space) then an integrable map is measurable.  axiom is redundant.


Comment: Also when domain is  Euclidean space ( lebesgue measure) but co domain is banach space( possibly infinite dimension) an integrable map is measurable again axiom is redundant.
 so i guess a specific example ( not there in literature) will involve Axiom of choice and a cardinal number greater than the power of continuum.
 incidentally when i saw comments for some other questions that they are not research level and for this question should reader look into monographs i think these comments are contradictory 
even the other questions wants an explicit construction of Hamel basis.